# How to automatically insert the data that is scanned using a barcode scanner in java?

Tags: java

When I put my cursor inside the JTextField and scan using a barcode scanner the value of the barcode will be put inside the JTextField and when I pressed the store button the data inside the JTextField will be stored in my MySQL Database, now I want my program to automatically stores the value inside the JTextField without pressing any button.

Comment: The question does not show much research and does not explain the problem well

Comment: You must to put an event when the text is "typed" in textbox

Comment: Trying to explain what you've done and what you're trying to do using only words in not a good idea. For one, it's difficult to do such that anyone actually understands what you mean. And many people on here speak English as a second or third language, thus may have a hard time grasping the explanation. Code would be much clearer.

Comment: Why not just send it to the database when you get a barcode scan?

Answer (score 1):

Add document change listener to textfield.

```
 // Listen for changes in the text
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    save(); // As per your requirement
  }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    save(); // As per your requirement
  }
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    save(); 
  }

  public void save() {
    /*
      Write your implementation for saving
    */
  }
});
```

More info on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to implement a listener on the scanner, you can listen to the Text change of the JTextField. Simply invoke the store action inside it. It is kind of a hack, but it has to work.

Answer (score -2):

In .net I would have written the call to store to data in the lost focus event of Textbox. Probably, similar event exists for JTextField as well.

Comment: But, you lose the focus by pressing a button, right? And the question says "without pressing any button"

Comment: This doesn't really provide a sufficient answer to the question and would thus have been better suited as a comment.